# How to zoom cinnamon or gnome terminal window to full size via bash?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, gnome, cinnamon

The question refers to the following environment:

- Linux Mint 64, Cinnamon, version 20.x

It is known that terminal cinnamon and gnome terminal windows and their fonts can be zoomed in size via terminal as follows:

Zoomed increase by one size step:

```
xdotool key Ctrl+plus
```

Zoomed reducing by one size step:

```
xdotool key Ctrl+minus
```

Zoome to the window and font to original size:

```
xdotool key Ctrl+0
```

Searched are a shortcut and or the appropriate xdotool command to zoom a window like a cinnamon or gnome terminal to windows full size ( without to hide the windows decorationhe).

The follow dont solve this. It can set a terminal window to full size and dont hide the decoration, but it is not zoomed, so the font size is not adapted to the window size as in the other examples mentioned above.

```
xdotool key Alt+F10
```

Comment: F11 has never been a "Zoom" in the way you describe it... as far as I known it has always been the same as "Maximize" in the `Alt`+`Space` -menu.

Comment: @Hannu, I didnt write F11 are zooming the window. I wrote, F11 dont solve the question, because it only set the terminal to full size.

Comment: And i explained that this never has, historically ;-}